# Using randint and while loop to simulate dice roll

Tags: python

I am creating a simple random dice roll but the code prints the same answer for each roll

```
from random import randint
x = randint(1, 6)

class Die():
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = 6

    def roll_die(self):
        print(x)

die_1 = Die(6)
roll_count = 0

while roll_count <= 10:
    die_1.roll_die()        
    roll_count += 1
```

I expect the rolls to be randomized but whatever the first roll is (i.e. 4), is each answer in the while loop

```
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
```

Comment: Incredibly [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only "roll" once. You want to use `x = randint(1, 6)` each time you call `roll_die()`:

```py
def roll_die():
  x = randint(1, 6)
  print(x)
```